# Force spacing for tikz pictures used as variables

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, spacing

I wish to typeset a math equation involving boxes of different sizes (which represent matrices of different sizes in my work).

What I have done so far is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzstyle{mymatrix} = [rectangle, draw = black, anchor=base]
\newcommand{\largetikzmatrix}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(x.base)]{\node[mymatrix,minimum width=35pt,minimum height=35pt,inner sep=0pt] (x) {\makebox[0pt]{\ensuremath{#1}}};}}
\newcommand{\talltikzmatrix}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(x.base)]{\node[mymatrix,minimum width=12pt, minimum height=35pt,inner sep=0pt] (x) {\makebox[0pt]{\ensuremath{#1}}};}}
\newcommand{\smalltikzmatrix}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(x.base)]{\node[mymatrix,minimum width=12pt, minimum height=12pt,inner sep=0pt] (x) {\makebox[0pt]{\ensuremath{#1}}};}}

\begin{document}
\[
\largetikzmatrix{Z_k}
=
\talltikzmatrix{N_k} \smalltikzmatrix{M_k}^{-1}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Note that I have used `\makebox[0pt]` to make sure that the text inside the nodes does not make them increase in size. I prefer a little clash between the subscript and the box, rather than increasing the node size (which would make things more difficult to understand).

The only thing I am not satisfied with is the lack of spacing between the $N_k$ node and the $M_k$ node. I would like to have the same spacing as there is normally between two variables in a math expression. I have looked for something like `\mathvar` to make sure that the pictures are interpreted as math variables (analogous to `\mathop` and `\mathrel`), but I don't see it, and frankly I am not even sure that this is really the issue here.

I know I can throw a `\,` in there artificially to make some space, but it would be good if I could understand why the TeX `normal' math spacing is not used here and how to fix this problem.

Comment: Do you have real matrices or symbolic ones (like above)? Are those boxes needed in real use case?

Comment: @HarishKumar I have edited for clarity -- I have boxes, not true matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no space between variables in math expression:

```
\[ a b c \]
```

gives you

[image]

But you can add the spce you want with `\`, `\quad`, ... which also wotk with your code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzstyle{mymatrix} = [rectangle, draw = black, anchor=base]
\newcommand{\largetikzmatrix}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(x.base)]{\node[mymatrix,minimum width=35pt,minimum height=35pt,inner sep=0pt] (x) {\makebox[0pt]{\ensuremath{#1}}};}}
\newcommand{\talltikzmatrix}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(x.base)]{\node[mymatrix,minimum width=12pt, minimum height=35pt,inner sep=0pt] (x) {\makebox[0pt]{\ensuremath{#1}}};}}
\newcommand{\smalltikzmatrix}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(x.base)]{\node[mymatrix,minimum width=12pt, minimum height=12pt,inner sep=0pt] (x) {\makebox[0pt]{\ensuremath{#1}}};}}

\begin{document}
\[
\largetikzmatrix{Z_k}
=
\talltikzmatrix{N_k}\ \smalltikzmatrix{M_k}^{-1}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense, it was my expectation that there had to be a spacing which was misguided.

Answer (score 1):

Ignasi already answered the space issue, so this is just an improvement on `tikz` drawing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}

\tikzset{ mymatrix/.style = {rectangle, draw = black, anchor=base},}
\newcommand{\largetikzmatrix}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(x.base)]{\draw[path picture={
            \node[anchor=center] (x) at (path picture bounding box.center) {$#1$};
          }] (-17pt,-17pt) rectangle (17pt,17pt);}}
\newcommand{\talltikzmatrix}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(x.base)]{\draw[path picture={
            \node[anchor=center] (x) at (path picture bounding box.center) {$#1$};
          }] (-6pt,-17pt) rectangle (6pt,17pt);}}
\newcommand{\smalltikzmatrix}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(x.base)]{\draw[path picture={
            \node[anchor=center] (x) at (path picture bounding box.center) {$#1$};
          }] (-6pt,-6pt) rectangle (6pt,6pt);}}


\begin{document}
\[
\largetikzmatrix{Z_k}
= 
\talltikzmatrix{N_k}\ \smalltikzmatrix{M_k}^{-1}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I see correctly, this clips the part of the text that goes outside the rectangular box, right? I guess I need to use two separate instructions to avoid it, a `\node` and a `\draw rectangle`. But I like your approach more than mine, thanks.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: It is better to clip rather than having text protruding outside `;-)`. On a serious note, you can change the dimensions of the rectangle suitably.